# Can you load Apache Spark DataSets from named pipes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am currently using XUbuntu 16.04, Apache Spark 2.1.1, IntelliJ, and Scala 2.11.8

I am trying to load some simple text data in CSV format into an Apache Spark Dataset but instead of using regular text files, I am dumping data into a named pipe and then I want to read that data directly into the DataSet.
It works perfectly if the data is a regular file, but the exact same data doesn’t work if it is coming from a named pipe. 
My Scala code is real simple and follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object PipeTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("PipeTest")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

     // Read data in from a text file and input to a DataSet    
    var dataFromTxt = spark.read.csv("csvData.txt")
    dataFromTxt.show()


     // Read data in from a pipe and input to a DataSet
    var dataFromPipe = spark.read.csv("csvData.pipe")
    dataFromPipe.show()
  }
}
```

The 1st code section loads the csv data from a regular file and works fine. The 2nd code section fails with the following error:

Exception in thread “main” java.io.IOException: Error accessing file: /home/andersonlab/test/csvData.pipe

Anyone know how you would go about using named pipes with Spark Datasets and getting something like the above to work?

Comment: what is a named pipe?